# Jquery autocomplete if not find data then show notification

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have added search drop-down with jquery. Its searching well. Now I want to add if input data not match with my array data then show a text message notification in below of input field and when text match with array then auto hide message notification . How can I do that?

```
<input type='text' title='Tags' id='tags' />
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var aTags = ["ask","always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet","force9", "westerners", "sport"];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: aTags
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the `response` event of the AutoComplete. It receives an object which contains an array of the matches made. If this array is empty you know there were no matches and you can show your message:

```js
var aTags = ["ask", "always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet", "force9", "westerners", "sport"];
var $noMatches = $('.no-matches');

$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: aTags,
  response: function(e, result) {
    $noMatches.hide();
    if (!result.content.length)
      $noMatches.show();
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  display: none;
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<input type='text' title='Tags' id='tags' />
<span class="no-matches">No matches!</span>
```

Comment: please check this link https://jsfiddle.net/Sakib00123/jjc05c4h/1/  . 1st time data not match that why its showing 'not match' message. its good, If data match with array then hide the message. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to call `hide()`, not `hide`. Then you'll need to add `show()` in the other case: https://jsfiddle.net/jjc05c4h/2/. Also note that it's `message`, not `messag`. I'd do it the way I did in my example though. Your logic just adds needless complication

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your HTML it works

```
<div class="ui-widget"><input type='text' title='Tags' id='tags' /></div>
```

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question being asked.

Comment: ui-widget is jquery-ui class and you can use this to get easily

<div role="status" aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="additions" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><div>No search results.</div></div>